# Увеличить скорость выполнения sql запроса

Tags: mysql, sql

Необходимо сделать выборку id из таблицы "tab1", которых нет в таблице "tab2". Я использую для этого такой запрос:

```js
SELECT
  `tab1`.`id`
FROM
  `tab1` 
  LEFT JOIN `tab2`  ON (
    `tab1`.`id` = `tab2`.`id`
  )
WHERE
  `tab2`.`id` IS NULL
LIMIT 1000;
```

И этот скрипт отлично работает с некоторыми таблицами, но в одной он не отрабатывает, возможно(это предположение), это из-за того, что "tab1" имеет большое кол-во повторений id(8 - 10 раз). "tab2" содержит только уникальные значения "id" Запрос просто перестаёт выполнятся и всё, а с другими таблицами отрабатывает быстро(даже с таблицами, которые имеют больше записей в разы), в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Стоит заменить LEFT JOIN на WHERE NOT EXISTS

Comment: Ну и - LIMIT без ORDER BY вернёт случайные записи. И если потом захочется LIMIT 1000,1000 - вот не факт что всё будет ровно.

Comment: Да, посмотрите, на проблемной паре таблиц есть индексы по полю `id`?

Comment: Спасибо за ваши комментарии, вы можете полное решение написать, пожалуйста?

Comment: @Герман Борисов в mySql LEFT JOIN имеет более высокую скорость